# I need to compare list of names against what's already in database with MySQL workbench

Tags: mysql

With MySQL Workbench, I need to compare a list of names against names already in database and have results be only devices not found. What query should I use?

123 names. I just want what's not in database to be returned. Thanks-

Answer (score 0):

Store the 123 names into a temporary table:

```
create temporary table tmp (name varchar(50));
insert into tmp (name) values
    ('name1'),
    ('name12'),
    ('name123'),
    ('name124');
```

Then look what's not in the `devices` table using an *antijoin*:

```
select t.name
from tmp t
left join devices d on d.name = t.name
where d.name is null
```